# How does the Form Tag Helper determine the rendered form action?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm using ASP.NET CORE using MVC. I've got an `Area` setup called 'Profile', with a `UserController` that has an `Edit` action. I don't feel I'm breaking any new ground here.

If I got to this URL:

`/Profile/User/Edit/100`

And I have a view that looks like this:

`<form method="post" role="form" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Edit">`

Why does the HTML render like this:

`<form method="post" role="form" action="/Profile/User/Edit">`

Instead of this (Note the "/100"):

`<form method="post" role="form" action="/Profile/User/Edit/100">`

I realize I can side-step the Form Tag Helper or otherwise work around it, but it seems like this should 'just work'.

This is how my routes are currently configured:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areaRoute",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   template: "{area:exists=Home}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET Core are you running? The behavior depends on how your routes are configured. Could you share how they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ordering routes, make sure to put the routes with larger number of segments before routes with lesser number of segments. Also why do you need 2 similar looking routes above?

Can you try after modifying routes like below?

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "areaRoute",
            template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
               template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

Comment: This did it! I thought routes only routed the request, but I guess it does more than that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yeah, they are even used for link generation. And when generating link, MVC sees tries to use the route data present in current request context and goes top-down the route list to see which route matches.